# EAN13 checksum class for python 3 using comprehension list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, map-function

I'm trying to change this python 2 class to make it works in python 3
But unfortunatly i'm stuck with comprehension list

Here is the original class:

```
class GTIN(object):

def __init__(self, barcode=''):
    self.barcode = barcode

def __checkDigit(self, digits):
        total = sum(digits) + sum(map(lambda d: d*2, digits[-1::-2]))
        return (10 - (total % 10)) % 10

def validateCheckDigit(self, barcode=''):
    barcode = (barcode if barcode else self.barcode)
    if len(barcode) in (8,12,13,14) and barcode.isdigit():
        digits = map(int, barcode)
        checkDigit = self.__checkDigit( digits[0:-1] )
        return checkDigit == digits[-1]
    return False

def addCheckDigit(self, barcode=''):
    barcode = (barcode if barcode else self.barcode)
    if len(barcode) in (7,11,12,13) and barcode.isdigit():
        digits = map(int, barcode)
        return barcode + str(self.__checkDigit(digits))
    return ''
```

Here is where am I with my noob skill

```
class GTIN(object):

def __init__(self, barcode=''):
    self.barcode = barcode

def __checkDigit(self, digits):
        #total = sum(digits) + sum(map(lambda d: d*2, digits[-1::-2]))
        total = sum(digits) + sum([d*2 for d in digits[-1::-2]])
        return (10 - (total % 10)) % 10

def validateCheckDigit(self, barcode=''):
    barcode = (barcode if barcode else self.barcode)
    if len(barcode) in (8,12,13,14) and barcode.isdigit():
        #digits = map(int, barcode)
        digits = (int(s) for s in barcode)
        checkDigit = self.__checkDigit( digits[0:-1] )
        return checkDigit == digits[-1]
    return False

def addCheckDigit(self, barcode=''):
    barcode = (barcode if barcode else self.barcode)
    if len(barcode) in (7,11,12,13) and barcode.isdigit():
        #digits = map(int, barcode)
        digits = (int(s) for s in barcode)
        return barcode + str(self.__checkDigit(digits))
    return ''
```

I changed all map fonction by comprehension list but now i'm stuck with  this error

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why did you change all applications of `map` with list comprehensions? Where does the error appear? Do you know [what it means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288016/generator-object-is-not-subscriptable-error)?

Comment: It's my mistake sry i dit not noticed the () on my comprehension list ! Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
digits = (int(s) for s in barcode)
return barcode + str(self.__checkDigit(digits))
```

and later, in `__checkDigit`, you do

```
total = sum(digits) + sum([d*2 for d in digits[-1::-2]])
```

For `digits[-1::-2]` to work, `digits` has to be a list, or some other kind of "subscriptable". In Python 3, `map` returns a generator, so you changed it. But you changed it to just another kind of generator -- a generator expression.

You can either use a proper list comprehension (note the square brackets):

```
digits = [int(s) for s in barcode]
```

or stick with `map`, but turn the generator into a list:

```
digits = list(map(int, barcode))
```

Comment: Addendum: In the general case, another alternative might be using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of `[-1::-2]`, but `islice` does not support negative values for start, stop and step.

Comment: actually , It's my mistake i noticed that later i did not used well comprehension list, arghhh !!! Thanks for your support