# How to Store An Entire Row Or Column In A Variable in Python

Tags: python

i am trying to store one column in a single variable.but I cant

**code**

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("coordinates.xlsx")  
sh2 = wb['sheet2']
sh1 = wb['sheet1']
x1 = (wb['sheet2'].columns["B"]).values
print(x1)
```

**error**

```
 x1 = (wb['sheet2'].columns["B"]).values
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

why does this happen? is there any other way to store the entire data of single column in one variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["'generator' object is not subscriptable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288016/generator-object-is-not-subscriptable-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772758/10163595 gives you the specific answer you need. However by way of explanation, wb['sheet2'].columns is a generator object and can not be given a subscript.

You can use it as follows to access the individual columns and then cells:

```
for column in wb["sheet2"].columns:
    for cell in column:
        print(cell.value)
```

The column variable above is storing the entire content of a single column during each loop/iteration. The cell variable is storing the content of a single cell and you use the value property to access the data stored in each cell.

You could alternatively use the iter_cols() method to iterate through each column.

Comment: i want to store one column in one variable and a second column in the second variable.iter_cols I have choose range that is min col and max col. in my case there is no min col and max col because there is a particular column. can you please guide a little?

Comment: It's the same procedure as shown in the other answer. To store column A in a variable: "column_a = wb['sheet1']['A']". To store column B in a variable: "column_b = wb['sheet1']['B']".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("coordinates.xlsx")  
sh2 = wb['sheet2']
sh1 = wb['sheet1']['B']
x1 = [i.value for i in sh1]
print(x1)
```