# Filter a csv file (without panda) compilation error

Tags: python, csv

good evening, I have a problem is that I have to make 2 python files where TestFiltrador filters the columns of a .csv file and that has 2 columns exactly) and the other called: Testdefiltrado prints those 2 columns but I get this error.

TestFiltraor:

```
Almacenamiento_de_datos = namedtuple('DESAPARECIDOS_INDIA_2018_2020','Tipo_de_sangre,Nombres,Genero,Cuerpo,Distrito,'


#where are the columns CSV FILE
                                                                     'DENUNCIADO,Estatura,Edad,Cuando_Desparecio')


def Archivo_Csv(Archivo): 
    with open(Archivo, encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        lineador = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        next(lineador)
        lista =[(Almacenamiento_de_datos(Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO, float(Estatura), int(Edad),
                                     Cuando_Desparecio)for Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito,DENUNCIADO,
                                                           Estatura, Edad, Cuando_Desparecio in lineador)]
        return lista
#open the csv file and access it to


 Storage which is namedtuple save it in the variable l i s t a


def Todos_Los_nombres (lista):
    for i in lista:
        Nom = next(i['Nombres'], i ['Edad'])
        return Nom

#en list iterate and find me the columns EN: h o m b r e s, (int) E d a d
```

this would be the code to call it

```
def TestFiltrador (Desaparecidoscsv):
    Nom= Todos_Los_nombres(Desaparecidoscsv)
    print("Los nombres y sus edad son : ",Nom)
## Nom : iterates the first code above and prints
```

is this error

```
 Nom = next(i['Nombres'], i ['Edad'])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

how can i do ?
i hope they can helpe me , thank for see my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288032/4350650

Comment: That is not a compilation error, that's a runtime error

Comment: try the 2 solutions in the forum and I could not in my case has not suffered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a generator expression here:

```py
lista = [
    (
        Almacenamiento_de_datos(
            Tipo_de_sangre,
            Nombres,
            Genero,
            Cuerpo,
            Distrito,
            DENUNCIADO,
            float(Estatura),
            int(Edad),
            Cuando_Desparecio,
        )
        for Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO, Estatura, Edad, Cuando_Desparecio in lineador
    )
]
```

If you want a list of `namedtuple`s, do this:

```py
lista = [
    Almacenamiento_de_datos(
        Tipo_de_sangre,
        Nombres,
        Genero,
        Cuerpo,
        Distrito,
        DENUNCIADO,
        float(Estatura),
        int(Edad),
        Cuando_Desparecio,
    )
    for Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO, Estatura, Edad, Cuando_Desparecio in lineador
]
```

Comment: organizing it that way can solve that problem for me? , thnaks for helpeme

Comment: It will remove the "generator" error. Not sure if there will be another error after that.