# How to write a MRJob python for matrix addition

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I have been trying to make simple matrix addition program with MRJob library. I have created this simple program as with a separate mapper and reducer it works fine locally and on Hadoop cluster now i am trying to create this program on a single class (MRJob) library. but i could not find the error i am getting, mapper function is working fine but reducer is not working correctly , I could not find any solution on the internet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Here is the input file (input.txt):**

```
a,0,0,10
a,0,1,20
a,0,2,30
a,1,0,40
a,1,1,50
a,1,2,60
a,2,0,70
a,2,1,80
a,2,2,90

b,0,0,1
b,0,1,2
b,0,2,3
b,1,0,4
b,1,1,5
b,1,2,6
b,2,0,7
b,2,1,8
b,2,2,9
```

**Here is the code file:**

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        key = row[0]
        value = row[1:]
        if key == 'a':
            yield key, value
        elif key == 'b':
            yield key, value

    def reducer(self, key, value):
        A = dict()
        B = dict()
        if key == 'a':
            A[int(value[0]), int(value[1])] = int(value[2])
        elif key == 'b':
            B[int(value[0]), int(value[1])] = int(value[2])

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                yield (row, col), A[(row, col)]+B[(row, col)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

**Error I am getting**

```
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for inline runner
Creating temp directory /tmp/MRJMatrix.ahsan.20220228.212900.538764
Running step 1 of 1...

Error while reading from /tmp/MRJMatrix.ahsan.20220228.212900.538764/step/000/reducer/00000/input:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MRJMatrix.py", line 29, in <module>
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 616, in run
    cls().execute()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 687, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 636, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 503, in run
    self._run()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 161, in _run
    self._run_step(step, step_num)
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 170, in _run_step
    self._run_streaming_step(step, step_num)
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 187, in _run_streaming_step
    self._run_reducers(step_num, num_reducer_tasks)
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 289, in _run_reducers
    self._run_multiple(
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 130, in _run_multiple
    func()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 746, in _run_task
    invoke_task(
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/inline.py", line 133, in invoke_task
    task.execute()
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 681, in execute
    self.run_reducer(self.options.step_num)
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 795, in run_reducer
    for k, v in self.reduce_pairs(read_lines(), step_num=step_num):
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 866, in reduce_pairs
    for k, v in self._combine_or_reduce_pairs(pairs, 'reducer', step_num):
  File "/home/ahsan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 889, in _combine_or_reduce_pairs
    for k, v in task(key, values) or ():
  File "MRJMatrix.py", line 19, in reducer
    A[int(value[0]), int(value[1])] = int(value[2])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

The reducer is input is like:
(a,[[values1]],[[values]]....)
So, now values is a generator, it is iterable, but you cannot access it as it was a list.
It's convenient for you, to convert values in a list and scroll though a list by a for loop.
As reference, you can see also here:["'generator' object is not subscriptable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288016/generator-object-is-not-subscriptable-error)

I hope that it is useful :)

cheers,